# SQL Server 2019 Polybase MongoDB user defined column was not found in the external table

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, polybase

I am setting up a Polybase against Azure CosmosDB (MongoDB API) in SQL Server 2019 and I am stuck creating a external table.

I created one sample document in Cosmos DB with following definition:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecc3fcd7791b617982fefa0"),
    "id" : "1",
    "products" : "2009",
    "item" : "Car",
    "type" : "Racecar"
}
```

[Snipped from Azure portal for sample collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGKVf.png)

When I run following statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mongodb.Products 
( 
[_id] NVARCHAR(24) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,  
[id] NVARCHAR(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
[products] NVARCHAR(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
[item] NVARCHAR(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
[type] NVARCHAR(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
) 
WITH ( 
LOCATION='Sales.Products', 
DATA_SOURCE= CosmosDB  
);
```

I get a message:

```
Msg 105083, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
105083;The following columns in the user defined schema are incompatible with the external table schema for table 'Products': user defined column: 'id' was not found in the external table, user defined column: 'products' was not found in the external table, user defined column: 'item' was not found in the external table, user defined column: 'type' was not found in the external table. The detected external table schema is: ([_id] NVARCHAR(24) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS NOT NULL).
```

Connections seems good. If I change Sales.Product I will get a message that table does not exist.

Comment: `Latin1_General_CI_AS` is a different collation than `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS`. Although they're both theoretically code page 1252 they treat some letters like `Ǹ` and `ǹ`  [differently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/windows-collation-name-transact-sql#remarks).

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this solved.  It seems if you are trying to connect to Azure CosmosDB Mongo DB API you will need to edit a file in your SQL Server.

You need to locate C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\Polybase\ODBC Drivers\PolyBase ODBC Driver for MongoDb.ini

and change two lines

From (does not work):
Driver=PolyBase ODBC Driver for MongoDb\2.3.8\MongoDBODBCsb64.dll
Setup=PolyBase ODBC Driver for MongoDb\2.3.8\MongoDBODBCsb64.dll

To (works)
Driver=PolyBase ODBC Driver for MongoDb\MongoDBODBCsb64.dll
Setup=PolyBase ODBC Driver for MongoDb\MongoDBODBCsb64.dll

This was a solution provided by Microsoft support team.